# update variable inside function in python server

Tags: python, variables

So my problem is that im making this server, and i want it to be able to shutdown the server by sending a 's' to the server but not matter what i try i am unable to update data(as you can see i have tried both return and global but can't get it to work :(), it stays empty, could i get a tip for this? really new to python so if possible make it easy to understand.

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import * 
host = ''
port = 4444
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(1)
print('waiting for connetion')
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('welcome, type your data'))

    while True:
        global data
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        reply = 'server output: '+ data
        if not data:
            print('connetion lost')
            return data
            break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
    conn.close()


while True:
    global data
    data = ''
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('connected to: '+ addr[0]+ ':' +str(addr[1])) 
    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
    print(data)
    if data == 's':
        print('shutting down server goodbye....')
        s.close()
        exit()
```

Comment: How do you expect to get data back if you wrote something like `if not data: return data` ? It's guaranteed to return nothing. And you don't check anywhere for the return of `start_new_thread`, so you do not really try this way. Going trough global seems like a massive race condition.

Comment: okey thanks, really new to python and coding overall, used a lot of stuff i found around the internet to make it go together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At about line 38, change it to

```
while True:        
        if data and data.strip() == 's':
            print('shutting down server goodbye....')
            s.close()
            exit()
```

There are still many improvements that could be made to the code, however this change will cause the script to exit if an 's' is detected.

In your code the checking for data == 's' was failing for two reasons:

- The check only ran once and then the main thread went idle. By looping you can check the data value in the future.
- The data value is actually `s\r\n` so you have to trim the newline

Comment: okey thank you, with this and the other comment i think i understand how to make this work better, still very new to programming :) fun to learn

Comment: you are welcome. please mark my answer as accepted, or upvote it, as that is the best way to say 'thanks' on SO.

Comment: got ya:D new to stackoverflow aswell